# Load the view/template once server response received in angularjs app

Tags: angularjs, service, view, server

I have the following code and it displays blan as data is not initialized at the time of page load,. So how can I push it until data response from teh server is received? I used "Controller Activate" suggested by John Papa, but it did not help. I am doing something wrongly?

```html
<dynamic-form ng-show="formTemplate.$resolved" class="form_dynamic" id="form-id" template="formTemplate" ng-model="formData"> {{formTemplate}}
</dynamic-form>
```

```css
$scope.formTemplate = [];

register();
        
    function register() {
      //...
      console.log("registerForm..form.." );

      

      var service = ServiceFactory.getFormData();
      //Uncomment when actual server is connected
      $scope.formTemplate =
      service
          .then(ok )
          .catch(reject)
          .finally(final);

         
    
    };

processing happens in ok and value is returned.
```

Comment: @mtamma, any idea here?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got the answer:

I used:

ng-if="formTemplate.length" in -

```html
<dynamic-form ng-submit="register.registerUser(formData)" ng-if="formTemplate.length" class="form_dynamic" id="form-id" template="formTemplate" ng-model="formData" ></dynamic-form>
```